# How to mock a method inside another method with Python unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am struggling to mock a method inside another method i.e Let's say I have 2 classes A, B as follows:

```
class A:
    def method_A(self):
        return "Hi"
class B:
    def method_B(self):
        instance_A = A()
        result = instance_A.method_A()
        print(result)
```

Here I want to mock **method_A** while testing **method_B** but can't find a way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to test method_B by mocking mothod_A?

Comment: Yes, I want to test method_B by mocking method_A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
class A:
    def method_A(self):
        return "Hi"
class B:
    def method_B(self):
        instance_A = A()
        result = instance_A.method_A()
        return result

import mock

def mock_A(self):
    return 'Bye'


def test_method_B():
    with mock.patch.object(A, 'method_A', new=mock_A):
        result = B().method_B()
        assert result == 'Bye'
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by mocking a method?
If you mean why your code isn't doing anything that's because you need to call the method
afterwards:-

```
B.method_B()
```

Maybe that helps somehow, if not could you explain the problem a lil'bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case first you wanna import mock library by simply typing `import mock`

then you wanna create a function for
1) Mocking

```
def mocking_method_A(self):
return Some_value
```

2)Testing

```
def testing_method_B():
    with mock.patch.object(A, 'method_A', new=mocking_A):
        result = B().method_B()
        assert result == Some_value
```